# kebab-case in angular 2 selectors (tslint)

Tags: angular, jslint, tslint

This is my `tslint.json` file:

```
{
  "rulesDirectory": [
    "node_modules/codelyzer"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "class-name": true,
    "comment-format": [
      true,
      "check-space"
    ],
    "curly": true,
    "eofline": true,
    "forin": false,
    "indent": [
      true,
      "spaces"
    ],
    "label-position": true,
    "label-undefined": true,
    "max-line-length": [
      true,
      140
    ],
    "member-access": false,
    "member-ordering": [
      true,
      "static-before-instance",
      "variables-before-functions"
    ],
    "no-arg": true,
    "no-bitwise": true,
    "no-console": [
      true,
      "debug",
      "info",
      "time",
      "timeEnd",
      "trace"
    ],
    "no-construct": true,
    "no-debugger": true,
    "no-duplicate-key": true,
    "no-duplicate-variable": true,
    "no-empty": false,
    "no-eval": true,
    "no-inferrable-types": true,
    "no-shadowed-variable": true,
    "no-string-literal": false,
    "no-switch-case-fall-through": true,
    "no-trailing-whitespace": false,
    "no-unused-expression": true,
    "no-unused-variable": true,
    "no-unreachable": true,
    "no-use-before-declare": true,
    "no-var-keyword": true,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "one-line": [
      true,
      "check-open-brace",
      "check-catch",
      "check-else",
      "check-whitespace"
    ],
    "quotemark": [
      true,
      "single"
    ],
    "radix": true,
    "semicolon": [
      "always"
    ],
    "triple-equals": [
      true,
      "allow-null-check"
    ],
    "typedef-whitespace": [
      true,
      {
        "call-signature": "nospace",
        "index-signature": "nospace",
        "parameter": "nospace",
        "property-declaration": "nospace",
        "variable-declaration": "nospace"
      }
    ],
    "variable-name": false,
    "whitespace": [
      true,
      "check-branch",
      "check-decl",
      "check-operator",
      "check-separator",
      "check-type"
    ],

    "directive-selector-prefix": [false, "app"],
    "component-selector-prefix": [false, "app"],
    "directive-selector-name": [true, "camelCase"],
    "component-selector-name": [false, "kebab-case"],
    "directive-selector-type": [true, "attribute"],
    "component-selector-type": [true, "element"],
    "use-input-property-decorator": true,
    "use-output-property-decorator": true,
    "use-host-property-decorator": true,
    "no-input-rename": true,
    "no-output-rename": true,
    "use-life-cycle-interface": true,
    "use-pipe-transform-interface": true,
    "component-class-suffix": true,
    "directive-class-suffix": true
  }
}
```

I've got component selector name set to kebab-case. When I run a lint, I get a bunch of errors in my components saying that... The selector of the component "AdminComponent" should be named kebab-case.

But when I go to the component definition, this is what it is:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'admin',
    templateUrl: 'admin.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['admin.component.css'],
    providers: []
})
```

The selector is only one word, and doesn't require a kebab-case selector... how can I fix this?

Comment: I just had a similar issue and solved it [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56587971/5640649). Hope it helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know how to prevent this warning, but regarding to the official Angular Styleguide you should use your own prefix for a selector name:

https://angular.io/styleguide#02-07

> Do use a custom prefix for a component selector. For example, the prefix toh represents from Tour of Heroes and the prefix admin represents an admin feature area.
>
> Why? Prevents element name collisions with components in other apps and with native HTML elements.