# How to disable tslint rule for Angular style guide: "The selector should be prefixed by <prefix>"?

Tags: angular, tslint, codelyzer

I have an Angular test for some component which uses the directive `ngb-pagination` from [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home).

Now, in my test I mock this component as follow:

```
// on next line I get: The selector should be prefixed by "<prefix>" (https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-02-07) (component-selector)
@Component({ template: ``, selector: 'ngb-pagination' })
class DummyNgPagination {
    // some data here, not relevant in to the question
}
```

In the line where it is placed the `@Component` annotation I get a *tslint* error pointing to [Style 02-07](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-02-07).

I tried to disable the rule by doing the following, but the result is the same.

```
// tslint:disable-next-line:directive-selector
@Component({ template: ``, selector: 'ngb-pagination' })
```

**How can I disable that rule for that specific line?**

PS:

- Here is the real [angular project](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/gms/tree/master/client) in case you want to check any resource configuration.
- There is a similar question ([kebab-case in angular 2 selectors (tslint)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41732207/5640649)) but the OP just decided to live with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule `directive-selector` works for the `@Directive` decorator.

For a `@Component` you need to use `component-selector`

For example:

```
// tslint:disable-next-line:component-selector
@Component({ template: ``, selector: 'ngb-pagination' })
```

Comment: What a Merry Christmas this is!!!! Nice example.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Remove prefix rule from .eslintrc.json

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can set that inside your `angular.json` file inside `scematics` entry like so:

You can set it for both Components and directives

```
"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": ""
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": ""
    }
}
```

And if you are using the command line and you don't generate components/directives frequently, you can do that using the command line like so:

`ng generate component my-component --prefix ""`